# Change SCSS variable value on final file

Tags: sass

I have two files: `_partial.scss` which is imported by `file.scss`.

I have some variables on `_partial.scss`, and I want to change the values of the variables in `file.scss` but the changes aren't showing up.

Let's say I have `$var: #000000;` in `_partial.scss`. If I try to do `$var: #AAAAAA;` on `file.scss` the value of the variable does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

The code:

_partial.scss:

```
 $var: #FFFFFF;

 body {
   color: $var;
 }
```

file.scss:

```
 $var: #000000;
 @import 'partial';
```

The ouput is:

```
 body {
   color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

I want it to be

```
 body {
   color: #000000;
 }
```

Comment: May we have some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way around this without modifying your `_partial.scss` file.

If you want to have **default variables**, that you can override on `@import` you need to use them with **`!default`**:

**_partial.scss:**

```
 $var: #FFFFFF !default;

 body {
   color: $var;
 }
```

**file.scss:**

```
 $var: #000000;
 @import 'partial';
```

**Output CSS:**

```
 body {
   color: black;
 }
```

Otherwise whichever value is assigned last overrides the one before.

Another option is to define all **variables in a separate file** (e.g. `_variables.scss`) outside of `_partial.scss` ... then you can override/modify them (for example directly in `file.scss` if you wish) before importing `_partial.scss`.

Comment: Looks like adding the !default keyword fixed the issue! I actually tried using a different file for the variables before but that did not solve it. Thanks a lot!